# Spring OAuth shows default username / password form

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I had following two classes:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OauthDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OauthDemo.class, args);
    }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RestDemo {
    
    @GetMapping("/protected")
    public String protectedAccess() {
        return "Hello world!!";     
    }
}
```

I first added following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

After running the app, it auto generated password for default user `User` and logged it to the console. After entering these credentials, I was successfully able to retrieve "Hello World" response from above REST endpoint.

Then I replaced above dependency with OAuth dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But I did not configure any OAuth client information viz. the client ID and client secret. I thought it will give me error, but the output stayed the same as in case of `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency: it auto generated password for default user `User` and logged it to the console.

Why is it so? Is it the fallback of OAuth dependency because it could not find OAuth client information?

Answer (score 0):

If you check closely the POM of `spring-boot-starter-security-<version>.pom` It has below dependencies.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Now If you check the POM of `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client-<version>.pom` You will find the security dependency included in POM.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Now if you check the class

```
@AutoConfiguration(before = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnClass({ EnableWebSecurity.class, ClientRegistration.class })
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.SERVLET)
@Import({ OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class, OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class })
public class OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration {

}
```

Which basically uses the security libraries and enabled them, So internally its using the `org.springframework.security` which is showing you the default username and password form.

Comment: Please do not include images of code as it is against the rules

Comment: @Toerktumlare Which images of code? Spring pom is openly accessible and its open source , I am not sure which rule violation you have seen here. Could you please provide the link or documentation where it's written?

Comment: Few not so related questions: **Q1.** after successful authentication, when I hit `/api/protected` endpoint, it does not happen in OAuth recommended way, right? I mean, by first exchanging authorization code with access token and forwarding access token. Or spring boot security does indeed does this automatically? **Q2.** Or I have to add `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server` dependency for this to happen? **Q3.** Can I have same app both client and resource server? That is, can I add both corresponding dependencies to same pom?

Comment: the screenshot images of the pom from intellij, please copy out the pom.xml and provide it formatted in your answer. The how to ask under "help to reproduce" last bullet point says the following https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc` which refers to the question on meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question and im prretty sure this goes for all answers too.

Comment: I don't mind adding them as a source code, But those are given as reference. Copy pasting the complete pom doesn't make much of diffrence. But anyways will edit it as you have suggested.

Comment: Also, How to ask helps people to put the questions which can be reproduced and my answer was completely informative , there is nothing to reproduce and the snapshots were just hints or reference.

Comment: The poms contain xml so they should not be screenshots its as easy as that

Answer (score 0):

Login for comes from client libs. You should not depend on `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` when writing a **resource-server**.

Have a look at [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication) for configuring a resource server with JWT security. You can also have look at [that one](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken) to depend on `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` only, but this requires quite some more Java conf.

With this conf, you'll get 401 when user is not authenticated (or has invalid token) and 403 when authentication is valid but access is denied:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
            <!-- use spring-addons-webflux-jwt-resource-server instead for reactive apps -->
            <artifactId>spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
            <!-- use spring-addons-webflux-jwt-resource-server-test instead for reactive apps -->
            <artifactId>spring-addons-webflux-jwt-resource-server-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public static class WebSecurityConfig {
}
```

```
# shoud be set to where your authorization-server is
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.jwt-issuers[0].location=https://localhost:9443/realms/master

# shoud be configured with a list of private-claims this authorization-server puts user roles into
# below is default Keycloak conf for a `spring-addons` client with client roles mapper enabled
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.jwt-issuers[0].authorities.claims=realm_access.roles,resource_access.spring-addons.roles

# use IDE auto-completion or see SpringAddonsSecurityProperties javadoc for complete configuration properties list
```